# Reverse the group data as a different record using Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Split the group record in to different records :
for eg : 
Input : (A,(3,2,3))
Output in to 3 new lines: 
A,3
A,2
A,3

Can any one let me know the option to do this please?

Comment: Can you paste the describe query?. is it (3,2,3) is a string?

Comment: Hi Siva.Thanks for the reply. Please find the describe :                       grunt> describe C;
C: {group: chararray,rollingCnt: ()}       output is :(A,(5,2)) and i want to split the data in to each single line like line 1 : A,5 line 2 : A,2 .Please let me know, if you need more details

Comment: one question. In your UDF are you appending "(" and ")" in the output? and also can you paste the pigscript of last line ie C stmt?

Comment: I declared List in the UDF and adding the element to the list and then i convert in to tuple and sent back to pigscript.                    C = FOREACH B GENERATE $0,NewRollingCount(BagToString($1)) AS rollingCnt; DUMP C;

Comment: I tried this approach locally and its working fine.

Comment: Ok, I will try Siva.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when you convert the output of Arraylist to tuple then it will be difficult to achieve what you want, so I recommend this approach, so it will be easy to get the output .

In your UDF code, instead of creating Arraylist,  append the output into string seperated by comma and return back to pig script.

You final output should be like this from UDF as a string ie "3,2,3"

Then use the below code to get the result

```
C = FOREACH B GENERATE $0,NewRollingCount(BagToString($1)) AS rollingCnt
D = FOREACH C GENERATE $0,FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(rollingcnt));
DUMP D;
```